# If $(2x_{n+1}-x_n)$ converges to $x$, then show that $(x_n)$ converges to $x$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, cauchy-sequences

Let $(x_n)$ be a sequence in $\mathbb{R}$. Show that if $(2x_{n+1}-x_n)$ converges to $x$, then $(x_n)$ converges to $x$.

We don't know if the sequence $(x_n)$ is a convergent sequence or a cauchy sequence. If we are able to prove any one, then the problem is simple. Please provide any clue on how to go about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:**

\begin{align}
|x_m-x_n| =&\ \frac{1}{2}|2x_m-x_{m-1}+x_{m-1}-x_{n-1}+x_{n-1}-2x_n|\\
\leq&\ \frac{1}{2} |(2x_m-x_{m-1})-(2x_n-x_{n-1})|+\frac{1}{2}|x_{m-1}-x_{n-1}|.
\end{align}

**Probably a very bad hint!**

Comment: I would need another hint :p Because if $a_{n, m}$, $b_{n ,m}$ are nonnegative real sequences with $a_{n, m} \leq \frac12 b_{n, m} + \frac12 a_{n-1,m-1}$ and $b_{n, m} \to 0$, it need not be the case that $a_{n, m} \to 0$. Take for example $b = 0$ and $a_{n, m} = 2^{n-2m}$ for $n \geq m$, zero otherwise.

Comment: Okay. Take $n, n+1$ instead of $m, n$. Then use triangle inequality.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not convinced.

Comment: Okay. Note that $|x_{i+1}-x_i| \leq \sum^{i-1}_{k=0}\frac{1}{2^{k+1}}|y_{i+1-k}-y_{i-k}|+\frac{1}{2^i}|x_2-x_1| \leq \sum^{i-1}_{k=0}\frac{\varepsilon}{2^{k+1}}+\frac{1}{2^i}|x_2-x_1| $ since $\{y_n\}$ is Cauchy.

Comment: I see two problems: that doesn't show yet that $x_n$ is Cauchy, since we we have no way to control $|x_2-x_1|$; also you estimated $|y_2-y_1|$ by $\epsilon$...

Comment: It's a hint. Also, Cauchy is immediate by triangle inequality and geometric sum.

Comment: I see your concern, but we don't have to recursive back to $1$ and $2$.

Comment: Ok so I agree this gives $|x_{i+1} - x_i| \leq \epsilon$ for $i > N(\epsilon)$, but the triangle inequality gives you only $|x_n-x_m| \leq \epsilon \cdot |n-m|$...

Comment: Okay. You are correct. I can't seem to find any elementary ways to salvage the idea.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint.** Call $y_n = 2x_{n+1} - x_{n}$, let $N>0$ and look at $$\frac1{2^N} y_n + \frac1{2^{N-1}}y_{n+1} + \cdots + \frac12 y_{n+N-1} + y_{n+N}$$